# How to properly print non-English characters to a file with Perl?

Tags: perl

I am using Perl to print some data read from one file to another. Sometimes I read in non-English characters, such as accented characters like é. However, doing:

```
print FILE_HANDLER "... $variable ...";
```

does not keep the accents. The é actually gets printed out as "Ã©".

How can I print these characters out so that they're properly preserved? For more information, the files that I open and write to are done as such:

```
open READ_FILE, "<", "file.xml" or die $!;
open WRITE_FILE, ">", "file.txt" or die $!;
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: if you know the encoding of file.xml you can try `open READ_FILE, "<:<encoding>", "file.xml" or die $!;` read [perl open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

perldoc -f open says:

You may (and usually should) use the three-argument form of open to specify I/O layers (sometimes referred to as "disciplines") to apply to the handle that affect how the input and output are processed (see open and PerlIO for more details). For example:

```
 open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "filename")
 || die "can't open UTF-8 encoded filename: $!";
```

opens the UTF8-encoded file containing Unicode characters; see perluniintro

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help! I'll have to try it out when I get home later, and I'll be sure to reply with any success or lack thereof.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Everything went fine, except that on the write file I had to use encoding(Cp1252). That was what Eclipse was saying the file's encoding actually was, hmmm. Anyways, thanks for the help!